# insert header(left, center & right) in ms word using apache poi 3.11

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I need to insert header like the screenshot below in word document using apache poi

[image]
I have a code to insert the header. But it aligned to left like the screenshot below:

[image]

I used below code to insert header:

```
        // write header content
        XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument();
        CTSectPr sectPr = docx.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
        XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy policy = new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(docx,sectPr);
        CTP ctpHeader = CTP.Factory.newInstance();
        CTR ctrHeader = ctpHeader.addNewR();
        CTText ctHeader = ctrHeader.addNewT();
        String headerText = "This is header";
        ctHeader.setStringValue(headerText);
        XWPFParagraph headerParagraph = new XWPFParagraph(ctpHeader, docx);
        XWPFParagraph[] parsHeader = new XWPFParagraph[1];
        parsHeader[0] = headerParagraph;
        policy.createHeader(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT, parsHeader);

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("D:/giri.docx");
        docx.write(out);
        out.close();
        System.out.println("Done");
```

Comment: thank u in advance. please help me

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Excel, Word doesn't have left, centre and right headers - Word has a header. If you want three separate entries on a single line, you can format a paragraph with the appropriate alignment (e.g. centred/justified) and tab-stops (possibly 3 centred, or one each of left, centre and right), then insert tab characters into the text you're inserting. Alternatively, for multi-line inputs especially, you could insert a 3-column table with the appropriate cell formatting and send the outputs to the relevant cells.

In VBA, you might add a table to the page header using code like:

```
With ActiveDocument
  .Tables.Add Range:=.Sections.First.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=3, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed
End With
```

I'll leave it to you to do the Apache conversion.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I really new to this plugin. can u help how to insert a table & column in a header?

Answer (score 1):

XWPFHeader header=policy.getDefaultHeader();
        CTP ctpHeader = CTP.Factory.newInstance();

```
    CTR ctrHeader = ctpHeader.addNewR();
    CTText ctheader = ctrHeader.addNewT();

    String HeaderText = "TSS Word Documentsss";
    //ctheader.set(HeaderText);

    XWPFParagraph headerParagraph = new XWPFParagraph(ctpHeader, document);
    XWPFRun headerRun= headerParagraph.createRun();
    headerRun.setBold(true);
    headerRun.setFontSize(39);
    headerRun.setColor("808000");
    headerRun.setImprinted(true);
    headerRun.setShadow(true);
    headerRun.setCapitalized(true);
    headerRun.setUnderline(UnderlinePatterns.DOT_DOT_DASH);
    headerRun.setText(HeaderText);
    headerParagraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
    headerParagraph.setBorderBottom(Borders.BASIC_BLACK_DASHES);

    XWPFParagraph[] parsHeader = new XWPFParagraph[1];


    parsHeader[0] = headerParagraph;
    policy.createHeader(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT, parsHeader);
```